# Suggested reading order for Ultimates paperbacks

Tags: marvel, suggested-order, ultimates

I realize this kind of question is a bit of a gray area for the site, but following that disclaimer, I also know I can probably get a good answer here. The question is about reading order in the Ultimate universe, which had a limited scope and is hopefully therefore valid. Limiting it further, I'm restricting the question to ONLY trade paperbacks, i.e. collected editions, and primarily those covering the Avengers.

**Following [Ultimates 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785190252) ("Who Killed the Scarlet Witch"), which book would be the next to cover the Ultimate Avengers storyline?** It looks like [Ultimatum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785129456) would be the next major event, but after that the books seem to break up by character (ex. - [Ultimates: Thor Reborn](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785124829)).

If the best answer constitutes a long list and is therefore invalid for this site, I will also accept a starting point (with hopefully a link for where to look following that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Comic Book Herald site has a [Complete Guide to the Ultimate Universe](http://www.comicbookherald.com/the-complete-marvel-reading-order-guide/ultimate-marvel-universe-reading-order/). It includes the full reading over for every Ultimate universe publication, as well as shorter lists of "essentials".

For your specific point in the sequence, you're right that the various *Ultimatum* books are next, and then a long stretch of small 5-6 issue series before the next big named event (*Cataclysm*), but there are overarching storylines in those books, like "Ultimate Enemy" and "Death of Spider-Man".

There's a lot of information on the site, but to get you started, here's the suggested reading order for the next two sets of books -- the aftermath of *Ultimatum* and the *Ultimate Enemy* story arc. Note that, while there is a central plot to these issues, there isn't a lot of cross-over, so you can pretty much read each series in it's entirety before moving on to the next. Once you get to *Divided We Fall* it gets trickier.

### After Ultimatum

- *Ultimate Comics X* #1 – #5
- *Ultimate Comics Armor Wars* #1 – #4
- *Ultimate Comics Spider-Man* #1 – #6
- *Ultimate Comics Avengers* #1 – #6
- *Ultimate Comics Spider-Man* #7 – #15
- *Ultimate Comics Avengers 2* #1 – #6

### Ultimate Enemy Begins

- *Ultimate Enemy* #1 – #4
- *Ultimate Mystery* #1 – #4
- *Ultimate Doom* #1 – #4
- *Ultimate Comics Captain America* #1 – #4
- *Ultimate Comics New Ultimates* #1 – #5
- *Ultimate Comics Thor* #1 – #4
- *Ultimate Comics Avengers 3* #1 – #6